# Android Device Monitor turning Emulator OFFLINE

Tags: android-studio, emulation, offline, android-device-monitor

Yesterday, Android studio ran a few updates and thereafter, whenever I start Android Device Monitor (**ADM**), it put my **emulator** to **OFFLINE** and I cannot access it **even after killing the ADB server and restarting it**.

Until I start ADM, everything is fine; when I run the ADB Devices, I see the emulator online but the moment I start the ADM to pull the database out, it goes to OFFLINE.

**This is what I did to troubleshoot:**

1. ran adb kill-server
2. ran adb start-server
3. reset Android studio by deleting the setting folders
4. restarted the WINDOWS

but nothing helped by far and **any help would be greatly appreciated**.

This is on Android Studio 2.2.3

Comment: Since everything failed, I just uninstalled the Studio and re-installed it but have not updated to the latest because I do not know whether it will work or not :(  Now I am back to business!

Comment: I am getting the same issue after updating android studio to 2.2.3 on windows 10

Comment: the entire world must have this issue. im no mac and after the update in studio all emulators after api 22 show as offline. genymotion is working

Comment: Confirmed. I have Ubuntu `16.04`, Android Studio `2.3.3` and adb `1.0.32`. The emulator goes offline at the end of `react-native run-android` when adb crashes with `*** buffer overflow detected ***: adb terminated`. This after stating `error: more than one device/emulator` (note: there is only one).

Comment: Please any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I opened the ADM before launching the emulator.Then, I launched the Emulator together with the app not before.

Now the emulator is online.

Comment: This procedure works, but then android debugger shows the emulator is offline. So I can not debug the app simultaneously. :(

Answer (score 0):

I have given up on trying to figure out what is going on with ADM.  However, what I am currenly doing is, I have also installed the Canary version of Studio 3.x from here https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/index.html and everything works just fine with it.  I can even pull the database from the device without having any problem.  They both run side by side without having any issues on my Windows 7 work desktop.

The only downside of this, having to install both versions but as long as you have 16GB ram you should be fine.  That is what I in my PC.  Hope, this helps!